# I need help understanding how to turn this function into a stream for responsive and up-to-date results

Tags: angular, frontend, reactive-programming

So I implemented NGB-Typeahead in this project but the filtering function I found that works for it returns a result after the fact. I need to provide results that are current and I figure using a stream subscription should work but using the [ngbTypeahead] binding is confusing me.

This is in Angular 7.

Example:

User inputs: 000
Results: nothing because I have it wait for length 3 in the text and the results don't exist when the 3rd 
         character is typed

User inputs: previous + 0
Results: **000**00234 , 12**000**034 Note that only 3 are highlighted because this is the previous result. Now another result has been requested by the change but it won't show until the next character has been typed in.

```
<input type="text" class="search" [(ngModel)]="typeAheadModel" [ngbTypeahead]="filter" [resultTemplate]="result" [inputFormatter]="NumFormatter" />
```

```
filter = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(
        (term) =>
          term.length < 3
            ? []
            : (this.pageController.fetchPageSearchList(
                this._searchCriteriaSelection,
                term,
                '30'
              ),
              this._searchResults).slice(0, 5)
      )
    );
```

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to break this down into an action and a stream that can be subscribed to that will keep the results current without using the async-await methodology.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I cannot see where your problem is since you are doing the same as what the bootstrap guideline does, but I would test it with something other then '000'. You can have a look as well at this Stackblitz https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Comment: @IvanMihaylov The problem is that the results are always one step behind. If you do 000 in the input nothing comes up but a result is returned. Its a workflow issue, its trying to build the results dropdown window right before the results are returned from the api so nothing shows up until the next character is entered. This is the case for all inputs. if you tried to search 123F you would see all the results for 123 but not the F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `filter` out events getting passed down the event stream.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observer-filter?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)

```
filter = (text$: Observable < string > ) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(term => term.length > 3),
    switchMap(term => this.pageController.fetchPageSearchList(term));
```

Comment: is filter a custom pipe? and its giving me an error that term is unknown in the switchMap. Thank you for the prompt response though!

Comment: @CameronDavis yes it's an [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html), also the `term` is an arbitrary reference variable. You may call it whatever you'd like.

Comment: sorry to clarify the arbitrary variable that is used in the switchMap isnt picking up the text used in the field. What i meant to say is, how do you reference the field text where ```term``` is being used

Comment: idk why i cant @ you, it keeps disappearing when i try but alphapilgrim, thank you so much for throwing together that demo! i get what you mean and i think that would work if the api returned something formatted, but as it stands i get a csv file that i need to parse and format, then push into a model. so the filter function is calling the api on a change with length > 3, then that return gets formatted and that array of formatted stuff gets put into a stream. I need this function to call the api and use the stream to reflect the search values

Comment: @CameronDavis you can just continue to map over the result of the api request to format the response then continue to pass down to be used as model

Comment: alphapilgrim thank you so much! got it working just ended up using a ```switchmap``` and passing in the ```BehaviorSubject``` that receives the formatted information. works like a charm! on the off chance do you know how i can slice the results of the behaviorSubject? im not sure how to manipulate the information directly from the subject

Comment: @CameronDavis you can pipe the subject as well. So any subscriptions to that subject get the sliced/formatted output